# Email alert when field meets certain condition

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2012

I would like an email sent to me every time a certain field in my table is greater than zero. This is not something that happens often but I would like to be alerted when it does.

I only want to be emailed the new insert not any of the previous. In the example below, taking column 3 as the field of interest, Harry is the newest insert and column 3 is greater than zero. This is when I would like to be alerted, as you can see Jack's is greater than zero too but lets assume this is an older entry so I don't want this to appear on the email.

```
Name     Department      Column3   Column4   Column5
Harry    HR                 2         ABC      DEF
James    Sport              0         ABC      DEF
Jack     Finance            1         ABC      DEF
```

Relatively new with the email function in SQL but understand the basics below

```
use Database
go


begin
Execute msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail



 @recipients = 'emailaddress',
 @query = 'select Name, department, Column3 from    mytable

 where Column3 > 0 '



End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger that checks the values from the `INSERTED` table and executes `sp_send_dbmail` if this values exceeds the specified number can be used for this.  An example trigger is below.  Using `sp_send_dbmail` will require properly configuring Database Mail if you haven't already.  More details on Database Mail and setting this up can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/database-mail?view=sql-server-2017).  A cursor is used to send an email for each new row that was added/updated.  Since you only want to data from new or updated rows, this is obtained from the `INSERTED` table instead of a query, then used to build the `@body` parameter of `sp_send_dbmail`. 
 Note that `CONCAT` is used for a safeguard for nulls, as if multiple strings are added together with the `+` operator and one is null, the entire concatenated string will be null.  However if `CONCAT` is used the non-null strings will still be preserved.  A table variable is used to initially obtain the values from the `INSERTED` table which will later be feed into the cursor.  The `INSERTED` table will capture values from both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations.  From your question, it seems as though you still wanted to new value added to the table, so an `AFTER` trigger was used.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TestTrigger
ON YourDatabase.YourSchema.YourTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS  
BEGIN

DECLARE @NewColumn3 INT;
DECLARE @NewName VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @NewDepartment VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @Tab Table (COLUMN3 INT, NAME VARCHAR(25), DEPARTMENT VARCHAR(25));
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(2000);

INSERT INTO @Tab
SELECT COLUMN3, NAME, DEPARTMENT
FROM INSERTED

IF EXISTS((SELECT COLUMN3 FROM @Tab where COLUMN3 > 0))
BEGIN

--make sure to only add data from rows where COLUMN3 > 0
DECLARE EmailCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT COLUMN3, NAME, DEPARTMENT FROM @Tab WHERE COLUMN3 > 0

OPEN EmailCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM EmailCursor
INTO @NewVal, @NewName, @NewDepartment

--while there are still rows
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

--use CONCAT to avoid null value voiding message
SET @Message = CONCAT('Name ', @NewName, ' from department ', @NewDepartment, ' added a value of ', @NewVal) 

   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
        @profile_name = 'YourProfileName',  
        @recipients = 'EmailAddress@domain.com',  
        @body = @Message,
        @subject = 'Email Subject'; 

FETCH NEXT FROM EmailCursor 
INTO  @NewVal, @NewName, @NewDepartment

END

CLOSE EmailCursor

DEALLOCATE EmailCursor

END

END
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much for the detailed response, would you mind just explaining what this line does please, IF EXISTS((SELECT COLUMN3 FROM @Tab where COLUMN3 > 20))

Comment: @Clem_Fandango sorry that was a typo.  I used the value of 20 with test data before posting this and just updated my answer with 0 as in your question.  But that line serves to check if there was a value above 0 added, and it sends to emails only if there was.  Otherwise it won't create the cursor, execute sp_send_dbmail, etc. to avoid doing unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a quit similar answer using VBA instead of SQL. It could be a good solution however still need to understand the condition bit.

[Trigger email alert on excel based on date review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763911/trigger-email-alert-on-excel-based-on-date-review)

Would you consider switching to VBA?

Comment: VBA is way out of my comfort zone